# Seleccionar un selected:true a partir de otro Select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter-3

Por alguna razón no me selecciona sobre el segundo Select. No he hecho la pregunta sin revisar antes, pero no me funciona. Tengo un Select que dependiendo de lo que escoja se me va a seleccionar por defecto alguna de las opciones que ya tengo cargado en el otro. este es mi php:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Seleccione el Movimiento a realizar</label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker operation_id" id="operation_id" name="operation_id">
        <option style="display:none" selected="selected" value="">Choose here </option>
        <?php foreach ($operations as $mprod): ?>
        <option value=<?=$mprod->operation_id?> >
          <?=$mprod->operation_code?> -
            <?=$mprod->operation_name?>
        </option>
        <?php  endforeach;?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Almacen</label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker store_eid" id="store_eid" name="store_eid">
        <?php foreach ($stores as $store): ?>
        <option value=<?=$store->store_id?> >
          <?=$store->store_code?> -
            <?=$store->store_name?>
        </option>
        <?php  endforeach;?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y este es mi javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".operation_id").unbind('change');
$(".operation_id").change((e) => {
     $('select[id="store_eid"]').val(2)
});

</script>
```

Si se dan cuenta estoy pasando un valor por defecto a ver si así funciona y nada.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Disculpen, segui intentado y lo encontre:

```
let index = 2;
$('select[id=store_eid]').val(index);
$('.store_eid').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Solo debia recargar el Select despues de asignarle el valor.